# Time complexity of nested for-loop function

Tags: for-loop, nested, time-complexity

I have not found a similar case explained so if someone could take their time that'd be great!

```
for(int i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
    for(int = 1; j < n; j = j*2)
        sum++;
```

My reasoning is wrong since I know the answer to be O(log(N^2)log(N)).

To me it seems as though the outer loop runs N^2 times - for each outer loop iteration there's the inner loop which performs Log N operations each time.

So shouldn't it be O(N^2 * log N)?

Comment: `My reasoning is wrong since I know the answer to be O(log(N^2)log(N))` Source? This code is `O(n^2 log(n))`, maybe you did not copy it correctly?

Comment: Maybe you're right, I have not copied it wrong but I guess my professor could have gotten it wrong.